An RF IC mark 553G, no information found

SMD RF IC mark “M C 553 G”. Help me check the information of this IC.

That appears to be an MRF553G transistor, not an IC.
There's also an image of some for sale on Aliexpress here showing the same markings.

that is right,thanks
